# Error: Component X is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic 4 app: 
What's my mistake, why i am getting this error? It seems correct:

app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [ 
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'timetable', loadChildren: './timetable/timetable.module#TimetablePageModule' },
  { path: 'artistDetail/:id', loadChildren: './artist-detail/artist-detail.module#ArtistDetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'artist', loadChildren: './artist/artist.module#ArtistPageModule' },
  { path: 'venue', loadChildren: './venue/venue.module#VenuePageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

venue.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: VenuePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [VenuePage]
})
```

Comment: hi, try to check the order of the modules in the imports (it matters!)

Comment: Tried it like so: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts but still the same error..

Comment: but VenuePage component is importe somewhere?